# Apache flink Job Manager node runs out of JVM Metaspace quickly

Tags: apache-flink

I have an **Apache Flink cluster** (1.14.5) running on **kubernetes (AKS)**. Cluster is running in **session mode**. I am triggering **batch jobs** to it periodically.
Earlier the job manager **jvm metaspace** was configured to 256mb then later increased to **512 MB**. Whenever I run batch pipeline 3 to 4 times it completely fills up the metaspace and then it doesn't load any new batch job until I restart the job manager.
I do not see any class loader leaks in the application code. Also the triggered batch pipelines runs completely and marked in FINISHED state.

I have never seen the metaspace of job manager coming down from the time I restart cluster, it always keep growing up with every new batch pipeline run and eventually starts rejecting new batch jobs.

I need to know how flink manages/clean up this job manager metaspace periodically or it does not do it at all. Please suggest/help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "metaspace cleanup" per-se, since this is used for things like classes that have references, which shouldn't be removed.

Where you can run into problems is with code that hangs on to classes, typically indirectly via a classloader.

For example, if you're using any Hadoop file system code (directly or indirectly), then you can have the problem of a Hadoop daemon thread hanging onto classloaders. Hadoop also installs a JVM shutdown hook that does the same thing.